# Retrieve integer only from variable value

Tags: jquery

The following script retrieves the URL of the current page the user is on.

```
  $(location).attr('href');
    //pure javascript
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    // to show it in an alert window
    alert(window.location);
```

For example it would retrieve the following for me:

http://domain.com/Men/000101,en_US,sc.html?src=sale

I would then like to retrieve only the number that appears within that URL, so I would end up only with 000101 and save that in another variable. The problem is that each url has a different sized number. Is this possible?

THanks!

Comment: is posible for you use regexp?... post some URLs to see how are created, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var num = pathname.split('/').pop().split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to strip everything but the digits:

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
var digitsInPathName = pathName.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Note this is a naive solution and will break if there are digits anywhere else in the url, such as the domain or the querystring.